# Obtaining profiling information on running python app

Tags: python, debugging, profiling

If you have a python application in production (i.e not already running under a debugger or profiler), **is there any way to attach to the python process/instance and examine it?** It would be useful to know:

- what code is consuming time
- what is using memory

Any insight would be appreciated.